# effect of instance type on Method invocation from derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, instancetype

Suppose I have the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DerivedClass input = new DerivedClass();
    input.WriteName(); // Outputs BaseClass
}

class BaseClass
{
    public void WriteName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetName());//this.GetType()
    }

    protected string GetName()
    {
        return "BaseClass";
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected new string GetName()
    {
        return "DerivedClass";
    }
}
```

I ran some tests(using GetType()) about the object type from which `GetName()` Method is invoked (I mean `DerivedClass.GetName` from `WriteName`). I know that `WriteName` cannot see the new Method in `DerivedClass` class and `GetName` Method is hidden by `new` keyword, but does the instance type (`DerivedClass`) not have any effect on that?
is the type up-casted to base class when calling `GetName` Method? when calling from Main Method `DerivedClass.GetName` seems to provide the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The method is hidden by the new keyword in the derived class. But this is called from the base and it will always call the implementation from the base class. Even the following code will print the "BaseClass":

```
public void WriteName()
{
        string className = "";
        if (this is DerivedClass)
        {
            className = ((DerivedClass)this).GetName();
        }
        else
        {
            className = this.GetName();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(className);
}
```

Comment: So what about DerivedClass type? any implicit conversion to BaseClass to invoke the method?

Comment: If you want to call the derived class method you will need to mark the BaseClass method with virtual and the derived method with override. This way if the object is of the derived type it will call the method from the derived class.

Comment: yes I am aware of that but confused how it is resolved to call  `BaseClass.GetName()` while the type is still `DerivedClass`?